# how to keep oldest file in same directory

Tags: shell-script, files, timestamps

I had 2 directories "../in/" and "../temp/".My question is how to write bash script to keep the oldest file or directories in same ../in/ directory and remaining files or directories are moved to ../temp/ directory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been answered before. Several times, even. Search the site. Earlier questions should have the tags [tag:timestamps] and [tag:files].

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler ways to do this if one can assume that no file names has white space or newlines in its name.  In the modern world, one cannot assume this and, besides, it is bad form to write scripts so fragile that they fail if such a legal file name is found.

To be safe, use the following (GNU tools may be required):

```
find ../ini/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -nz | sed -Ezn '2,$s/[^ ]* //p' | xargs --null mv -t ../temp/
```

This moves all but the oldest file in `../ini/` to `../temp/`.

#### How it works

- `find ../ini/ -type f`

  This finds all regular files in directory `../ini`.
- `-printf '%T@ %p\0'`

  This prints the timestamp and name of the files found in a nul-separated string.
- `sort -nz`

  This does a numeric sort on the nul-separated string.  When this is done, the oldest file is listed first.
- `sed -Ezn '2,$s/[^ ]* //p'`

  This prints all file names except for the first one.  It also removes the timestamp.
- `xargs --null mv -t ../temp/`

  This executes a `mv` command on these files, sending them to the `../temp/` directory.

#### Using tools that don't support nul-separated items

The above assumed tools that supported `\0` separated items. Modern versions of Linux (GNU) do support this.  When using an which OS does not, there are various work-arounds.  The following use newline-separated items and thus should be compatible with older tools:

```
find ../ini/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | sed -En '2,$s/[^ ]* //p' | xargs -d'\n' mv -t ../temp/
```

This will fail if any files have names which contain newlines.

Comment: Thanks for your response.How it can be used without GNU tool.

Comment: @Bantu Just to clarify, you tagged this question "Linux".  That means that you have GNU tools.  Are you using a different OS?  Or, are you having some other problem?

Comment: I am using that code in #!/bin/bash

Comment: I got this error.$ sed: invalid option -- 'z'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

Comment: @Bantu OK.  What OS are you on?  Also, I added an approach which doesn't require `-z`.